# Declare an string array inside a int array in Solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, arrays

I am using truffle and I am trying to pass during the deployment execution script a double array of prices inside my contract's constructor.
ie

In the migration file I have a 2 dimensional array. It's nested array contains a pair of prices.

```
var prices = [
  ['1223.456', '1223.456'],
  ['123.46', '12.1']
];
```

```
contract A {

   struct Price {
        string Price0;
        string Price1;
    }

    mapping (uint => Price) prices;

    constructor (int[][] memory _prices) public
    {

        for(uint i=0; i< _prices.length; i++) 
        {

          prices[i] = Price(
              _prices[i][0],
              _prices[i][1]
          );

        }
    }
}
```

How can I declare this inside my contract's constructor so that I can parse it right after?
What I saw so far is that I can declare a 2 dimensional array with the same type
ie

```
uint[][] prices;
// or
string[][] prices;
```

but these are not working since in my double array the 1-level key is of type integer and the value of the 2-level is of type string.

Comment: If you want to get suggestions for the actual solution that you should apply, then you'll need to show what you intend to do with the input to the constructor.

Comment: @goodvibration I added the code of constructor.

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array if you always access `[1]`?

Comment: Thank you for the indication. That was a mistake :)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense (and doesn't compile either). Fields `Price0` and `Price1` are of type `string`. The input `_prices` array contains items of type `int`, which you cannot assign to variables of type `string`!!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with your point but this is exactly what I want. I want a way to declare correctly the ```_prices``` array so that I can pass the data that I mentioned in the beginning. As said I want to pass to the contract's contractor an array of price arrays during deployment.

Comment: You want to pass an array of integers, and then assign those integers to string variables? Why not just pass an array of strings???

Comment: The idea here is that it's array has some prices per hour. So I cannot simply put all together in one array as it will destroy the classification.

Comment: You did not refer to the question in the comment.

Comment: Which question? I updated the 2D array that I want to pass to my contract. Maybe now is more clear?

Comment: [This message](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91864/declare-an-string-array-inside-a-int-array-in-solidity?noredirect=1#comment113234_91864) (4 above here).

Comment: I did. I want to pass a collection of arrays. It's internal array would have a pair of string prices. Here is a link of the same code in javascript that works. https://www.codepile.net/pile/NqbZgVqB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
constructor(string[] memory _prices0, string[] memory _prices1) public {
    uint256 length = _prices0.length;
    require(length == _prices1.length, "invalid input length");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        prices[i] = Price({
            Price0: _prices0[i],
            Price1: _prices1[i]
        });
    }
}
```

Then, from JS, you can call it with:

```
var prices0 = ['1223.456', '123.46'];
var prices1 = ['1223.456', '12.1'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This actually works really good. The only thing is that I need to prepare the data in javascript accordingly so to meet your logic. Out of curiosity is there any other way where you don't have to split the data to two groups just like the javascript example that I provided?

Comment: @spyrAlex: As of solc 0.8.0, passing structs as input to public and external functions is natively supported. If you switch to this compiler version, then I suppose that you can pass a single array of structures. BTW, feel free to accept my answer by clicking on the V next to it (if it has indeed answered your question).

Comment: I tried also with the latest solc 0.8.0 and also works as I wanted initially. Thanks again!